# htaccess not working when I use rewriterule /canonical/url to another with params ?title=some-title

Tags: server, apache2, php

I am using a web hosting server that is receiving urls like:

https://www.domain.es/blog/name-of-article

The .htaccess is trying to transform those urls to the GET form:

https://www.domain-name.es/blog-art.php?title=name-of-article

To do it I have, between any others, these two rules in the .htaccess:

```
# blog.php
RewriteRule ^(.*blog)$ https://www.my-domain.es/blog.php [NC,R=301]
# blog_art.php`
RewriteRule ^(.*blog)\/(.+)$ https://www.my-domain.es/blog_art.php?titulo=$2 [NC,R=301]
```

The second one is NOT working, it only works on my PC when it is localhost, but NOT working when it is on the web hosting server.

Why?

Any help would be appreciated.

Please, help.

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu ? Try asking in an Apache forum.

Answer (score 0):

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77022505/htaccess-not-working-when-i-use-rewriterule-canonical-url-to-another-with-param/77034237#77034237

Thank you very much, CBroe

I solved this before reading your post with:

```
Options -Multiviews


# blog.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*blog$
RewriteRule .*blog$ https://localhost:33/blog.php [NC,R=302,L]

# blog_art.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*blog/(.+)$
RewriteRule .*blog/(.+)$ https://localhost:33/blog_art.php?titulo=$1 [NC,R=302,L]
```

...

You are right that I don´t need `.*` before `blog$` nor I need to capture it. I did it without knowing very much and in the thought of "just in case".

I had to read documentation and do tests.

I found a very good htaccess test page that I strongly recommend:

https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/

I found it at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules

Which I strongly recommend too even more.

You are right too to advise me to use R=302 instead in my tests.

And I could recommend too to have a look at the apache documentation about rewrite rule flags:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

So you were right in all.

Thank you very much.

It is fixed now.